# How to reduce the cost of healthcare without paying for health insurance?

Tags: usa, insurance

So it has come to this...the new US healthcare laws require that all health insurance plans subsidize some things which I find to be immoral (specifically abortifacients, contraception, and sterilization). Anyone who does not sign up for a "government approved" plan will face fines. However, I'm willing to pay the fines. Now I'm left with trying to figure out how to create my own "personal health insurance plan".

I've always had insurance so I'm a bit ignorant of how things have been working for the uninsured. Aside from setting up a savings account used for emergencies, what can one do to pay for and/or reduce the cost of health care? Are there certain types of healthcare providers who accept cash instead of insurance? Are there generic insurance plans that could be used in place of a real health insurance plan?

Comment: How does this relate to freelancing?

Comment: Only because I'm a freelancer and obtaining your own health insurance is a common task for freelancers. If you can think of a StackExchange site that would be better suited for this question, then by all means, transfer it over. This was the most relevant one that I could find.

Comment: This could work here as a question if you could rework it slightly to add the freelance angle in. It's not clear that this relates to freelancing from the question

Comment: Perhaps delete the "immorality" angle -- keeping focus on alternatives to group insurance.

Comment: This question is really more about personal finance, but I didn't think there was a StackExchange site for that, but I just found http://money.stackexchange.com/ I think this question is better suited there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my neighborhood there are many urgent-care providers who accept cash.  I've seen prices from $50 to $125.  This will get you through the easy stuff - flu, ear infection, pink eye, maybe (as a male, I can't vouch for this) female concerns -- the low hanging fruit.

Hospitals will take cash!  I think many hospitals bump up their prices as a way to finance the long process of them getting paid by the insurance companies, and I'm sure some will bump the rates down if you're paying cash.  But depending on the situation, you may be still looking at a whole lot of money (i.e. intensive or inpatient care).

Comment: I recently discovered that there are several "Healthcare cost sharing ministries" (such as http://samaritanministries.org), that meet the ACA requirements, that would be a good option for many freelancers. The cost and coverage is even better than traditional insurance.